# mupdf command does not install with homebrew

Tags: macos, homebrew

I tried to install MuPDF on OS X 10.11 using Homebrew:

```
brew install mupdf-tools
```

But when I try to use it from the command line (it doesn't show up on Launchpad) I get the following error:

```
mupdf example.pdf
-bash: mupdf: command not found
```

Looking around a bit, I find 64-bit executables for mudraw, mujstest and mutool in /usr/local/bin. These commands seem to work. But there is no executable for mupdf there or anywhere else that I can find (using the find command). Any ideas what has gone wrong?

Comment: mupdf-tools runs as `mutool`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run mupdf-x11

This works both for mupdf-tools and mupdf from homebrew since [they install the same binaries](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-x11/blob/master/mupdf.rb)

Comment: Thanks, MalCos. What I did in the end was 'brew install mupdf' and then, at the command line, 'mupdf-x11 example.pdf'. That worked.

Answer (score 5):

As of 2019, the accepted answer doesn't work for me.

I installed it with
`brew install mupdf`

After that, `mupdf-gl`, or `mupdf-gl <file path>` works. You might want to redirect STDOUT if you are using it in a script, for say in midnight commander like this:

```
# PDF
type/^PDF
    Open=mupdf-gl %f >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Comment: Excellent answer! I created a `mupdf` function in my `bashrc`: `mupdf () { mupdf-gl $1 >/dev/null 2>&1 & }`

Answer (score 3):

MalCos answer is correct. Just one addition:
MuPDF is a command line program and does not offer a graphical frontend to load files. I was missing this functionality and scripted [MuPDF Droplet](https://ente.limmat.ch/ftp/pub/software/applications/MuPDFDroplet/) for it.

[MuPDF Droplet](https://ente.limmat.ch/ftp/pub/software/applications/MuPDFDroplet/) is a **GUI for MuPDF under OS X** to drop your PDF/whateverMuPDFsupports-Files on to the program icon and they open with MuPDF. So you don't need to know the CLI command to start MuPDF...

[MuPDF Droplet](https://ente.limmat.ch/ftp/pub/software/applications/MuPDFDroplet/) was created using Platypus, the source is included in the distribution DMG. Download [MuPDF Droplet](https://ente.limmat.ch/ftp/pub/software/applications/MuPDFDroplet/), it's Open Source licensed under GPL.

Comment: Recent versions of MuPDF do have a GUI now.